# Recurring Profiles Additional Field

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring

I want to add an additional field to the orders that are created by Recurring Profiles, the field is in the database in the table sales_recurring_profile in the order_info column. The field I want on the orders is called tm_field1 and it adds delivery instructions to the orders.
Looks like this in the db

```
 s:9:"tm_field1";s:20:"Leave somewhere safe";
```

If I look in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Recurring/Profile.php
```

At the following

```
public function createOrder()
```

I can see the array is read by

```
$transferDataKays = array(
        'store_id',             'store_name',           'customer_id',          'customer_email',
        'customer_firstname',   'customer_lastname',    'customer_middlename',  'customer_prefix',
        'customer_suffix',      'customer_taxvat',      'customer_gender',      'customer_is_guest',
        'customer_note_notify', 'customer_group_id',    'customer_note',        'shipping_method',
        'shipping_description', 'base_currency_code',   'global_currency_code', 'order_currency_code',
        'store_currency_code',  'base_to_global_rate',  'base_to_order_rate',   'store_to_base_rate',
        'store_to_order_rate'
    );
```

Im guessing that just adding tm_field1 to the array is too easy and will need some additional code somewhere just not sure where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it really was that easy all I have done is add the field to the array and it works

```
$transferDataKays = array(
    'store_id',             'store_name',           'customer_id',          'customer_email',
    'customer_firstname',   'customer_lastname',    'customer_middlename',  'customer_prefix',
    'customer_suffix',      'customer_taxvat',      'customer_gender',      'customer_is_guest',
    'customer_note_notify', 'customer_group_id',    'customer_note',        'shipping_method',
    'shipping_description', 'base_currency_code',   'global_currency_code', 'order_currency_code',
    'store_currency_code',  'base_to_global_rate',  'base_to_order_rate',   'store_to_base_rate',
    'store_to_order_rate',   'tmfield1'
);
```